# Почему не работает код PHP с базой данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Начал учить php и mysql, пишу свой первый код. Создал базу через phpMyAdmin, пытаюсь подключить ее. По идее, если все работает, должно вывести 1 (true), но этого не происходит.

```
<?php                   //сервер  //логин и пароль //база данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mysql", "mysql", "userdata");
    $mysqli-> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //кодировка

    $success = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `email`, `date`) VALUES('admin', '".md5("admin")."', '".time("date")."')");
    echo $success;
    $mysqli-> close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Произвольный текст попробуйте вывести. Если не увидите то добавьте эти [три строки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/12593651) в самый верх, перед строкой `$mysqli = new...`

Comment: Простой текст выводится, а $success нет.

Comment: `if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { echo $mysqli->connect_error; die; }` - добавьте после строки `$mysqli = new...`

Comment: У меня все прекрасно отрабатывает.
`$admin = md5('admin');`
`$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
`$success = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email, date) VALUES ('admin', '$admin', '$time')");`. Смотрите корректность имени БД и логин | пасс

Comment: Странно, что вы оба указываете четыре поля, а передаете данных на три.